# Como puedo comparar datos de dos tabla en dos base de datos (MySQL) distintas?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

mi idea es comparar datos de una tabla especifica en dos base de datos diferentes, pero resulta que la 2da BD es externa, es de una sucursal distinta. Básicamente es obtener la diferencia de productos de las diferentes sucursales (cada sucursal tiene su propia BD). Encontré una consulta que pensé que me iba a poder ayudar pero no es para BD externa. Como resultado final quisiera formular un script para automatizar la comparación.

```
SELECT  t1.TABLE_NAME,
        CASE 
            WHEN t1.Columnas = t2.Columnas THEN '=' 
            ELSE 'distinto'
        END Numero
FROM (  SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) Columnas
        FROM BD_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) Columnas
            FROM BD_1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            GROUP BY TABLE_NAME) t2
    ON t1.TABLE_NAME = t2.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t1.TABLE_NAME  = 'MiTabla';
```

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes tú por *externa* en este contexto? ¿Otro servidor? ¿En la misma red o en sitio remoto? Es muy probable que la mejor solución en este caso sea consultar por separado ambas bases de datos y luego comparar por programación ambos conjuntos de datos. Sea como sea, faltan detalles importantes en tu pregunta.

Comment: Si perdón por la falta de detalles. La otra BD esta en otra Suc en otra provincia, a la que actualmente acceso de manera remota. Lo que hago actualmente es extraer los datos a comparar y así lo hago de manera local, pero no tengo idea si existe algún método en el entorno SQL para hacer este tipo de comparación entre dos BD que no están en el mismo servidor

Comment: En SQL Server existe lo que se conoce como *Linked Server*, que te permite conectar diferentes BD desde el mismo SGBD. Me parece que en MySQL existe algo parecido que se llama *Federated Engine*. Para más detalles puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371062/5587982) y los enlaces allí.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! No tenia idea que existía algo así, ya lo probare e intentare hacerlo nuevamente, si funciona me ahorraría muchísimo laburo.